# How to map json response to the model with different field names

Tags: c#, json, .net, asp.net-core, system.text.json

I am using an ASP.NET Core 6 and System.Text.Json library.

For example, I'm getting a response from the some API with the following structure

```
{
   "items": 
   [
       {
          "A": 1,
          "User": 
          {
             "Name": "John",
             "Age": 21,
             "Adress": "some str"
          },
       },
       {
          "A": 2,
          "User": 
          {
             "Name": "Alex",
             "Age": 22,
             "Adress": "some str2"
          },
       }
   ]
}
```

And I want to write this response to the model like `List<SomeEntity>`, where `SomeEntity` is

```
    public class SomeEntity
    {
        public int MyA { get; set; } // map to A
        public User MyUser { get; set; } // map to User
    }

    public class User
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string MyAge { get; set; } // map to Age
    }
```

How could I do it?

UPDATE:

Is it possible to map nested properties?

```
    public class SomeEntity
    {
        // should I add an attribute [JsonPropertyName("User:Name")] ?
        public string UserName{ get; set; } // map to User.Name
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the JsonPropertyName attribute

```
public class Model
{
    [JsonPropertyName("items")]
    public SomeEntity[] Items { get; set; }
}    
        
public class SomeEntity
{
    [JsonPropertyName("A")]
    public int MyA { get; set; } // map to A
    [JsonPropertyName("User")]
    public User MyUser { get; set; } // map to User
}
        
public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("Age")]
    public string MyAge { get; set; } // map to Age
}
```

You can then deserialize it with something like

```
JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Model>(response);
```

Comment: How do I handle a "items" property? 
And is it possible to do this without attributes?

Comment: I've added a `Model` class that contains an array of `SomeEntity`.

Comment: Yeah, I am using this way rn but it looks so ugly... 
Because of it I have to have a 1 useless class, is there any option to do this without `Model` class?
Also, I have updated a ticket, could you please take a look?

Comment: If you'd rather have the data in another format internally, you should make a structure that suits you and then map the deserialized json into that structure. `JsonSerializer` gives you a quick way to get json into a .NET structure, but it's limited in how much you can customize that structure.

Answer (score 1):

try this please

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(JsonPathConverter))]
   public class SomeEntity
    {
        [JsonProperty("items.User.Name")]
        public string UserName{ get; set; } // map to User.Name
    }
```

deserialize using :

```
JsonSerializer.Deserialize<SomeEntity>(response);
```

Comment: if you want to deserialize all the object to one class called SomeEntity, i can write full class code. just tell what properties you want to deserialize

Comment: Thanks! But I can do it on my own. So, to deserialize a response without creating an `Item` class I need to specify an `items` attribute to the all fields? 

Mb there is some `JsonDeserializingSetting` where I can add `items` to the ignore or smth like that?

Comment: you mean  [JsonIgnore]