# Convert multiple json to common json format using c#

Tags: c#, json, system.text.json

I am calling vendor Api to get json data, I want to convert that json to my custom structure.

Here is example

When I call student data, vendor returns data as below

```
{
 "Students": [
   {
     "FirstName":"Abc",
     "LastName":"pqr"
   },
   {
     "FirstName":"pqr",
     "LastName":"pqccr"
   }
]
}
```

When I call employee data, it returns as below

```
{
 "Employee": [
   {
     "FName":"Abc",
     "LName":"pqr"
   },
   {
     "FName":"pqr",
     "LName":"pqccr"
   }
]
}
```

I want to convert this to my own json format so that it would be easy to retrieve and manipulation something as below

```
{
 "Person": [

   {
     "First_Name":"Abc",
     "Last_Name":"pqr"
   },
   {
     "First_Name":"pqr",
     "Last_Name":"pqccr"
   }
]
}
```

I am using system.text.json to serialized and deserialize.

How can I convert to this common structure?

Trying with system.text.json to deserialize but don't have any idea on how can I convert to common structure

Comment: [Check this out, your need attributes to be able to map to the properties with different names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70917476/how-to-map-json-response-to-the-model-with-different-field-names)

Comment: Pascal_Underscore_Property_Names; ugh

Comment: You can have the common structure, with subclasses or interface implementations that represent the varied structure, but store their data in the common [parent's] attributes, parse it as an Student:IStudent/Student:Person but treat as the Person, you can write a converter, you can manipulate the json before you parse it..

Comment: Please edit your question to be more readable. Look at your last example - about 3/4 of it is blank lines. Always look at your post before hitting submit and ask yourself whether it's formatted how you'd want to read it if you were to come across the question.

Comment: Will you still have Employee and Student classes in your Project, or do you want just a Persons class into which the Employee and Student Jsons can get deserialized?

Comment: I just want person, don't want employee and student class ..

Comment: So basically, I want to call Api, get student / employee data then convert to person json then perform other operation like add in Db, show on form etc.

Comment: Since I think no one would be called "Students" or "Employee", you can use `string.Replace`.

Comment: It's just not to replace, I want to develop something generic because I have other similar structures which I want to convert to custom common structure. So need some idea to do..

Comment: @PrasadGavande I think what shingo meant is that when you get your json data, you run a check on the string if its Students or employees. And you run a string replace Method accoirding to that, so for example `if(jsonString.Contains("Student"){ jsonString = jsonString.Replace("FirstName", "First_Name");}` Of course the real code would be more generic/less redundant.

Comment: @SMSTJ Thanks, actually what I meant is more simple, e.g. `str.Replace(@"""Students"":", @"""Person"":").Replace(...`

Comment: @PrasadGavande Please clarify the rules of conversion, currently there's no common structure in your question, all the 3 json strings are equivalent, they only differ in key names. Also note the order of key-value pairs in a json object is not specified.

Comment: Thanks @SMSTJ and shingo , I will try for this

Comment: Arguably the correct/robust/easiest approach would be to deserialize data to dedicated `StudentsResponse` and `EmployeeResponse` types and map them to desired `PersonHolder` type. Is there particular reason why you don't want to do that?

Comment: @GuruStron I haven't tried this.. I will try . Thanks for an idea.. I just want something generic and yes robust.

Comment: @shingo, in real case, all 3 json will be equivalent and just change in key and it's property but actually they are same . Example fname and first name .. and order really matters here ? Because in real case order can be anything..

Comment: If order doesn't matters, how could you know `FirstName` , `FName` should be mapped to `First_Name`? Then you need to define maps, if they must be defined, what else can be said to be generic?

Comment: Also a fun thing one could do is to write custom converter PropertyAttributes

Answer (score 0):

convert json objects to model and use addrange to assign the data. Tried an example as below.
Consider test1 class as students and test2 as employee

```
public class test1
{
    public List<data> json1 { get; set; }
}

public class test2
{
    public List<data> json2 { get; set; }
}

public class test3
{
    public List<data> person { get; set; }
}

public class data
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
}
    
    var jsonData1 = new test1();
    var jsonData2 = new test2();
    var jsonData3 = new test3();

    jsonData1.json1 = new List<data>();
    jsonData1.json1.Add(new data { id = 1, Name = "Abc" });
    jsonData2.json2 = new List<data>();
    jsonData3.person = new List<data>();
    jsonData2.json2.Add(new data { id = 2, Name = "xyz" });
    jsonData3.person.AddRange(jsonData1.json1);
    jsonData3.person.AddRange(jsonData2.json2);
    string jsonString1 = JsonSerializer.Serialize<test3>(jsonData3);
```

Comment: Yeah but the if you wanna serialize that again it wont get the structure OP wants.

Comment: Edited the answer, please try this way. its working

Comment: Still not what OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to deserialize data to dedicated types (`StudentsResponse` and `EmployeeResponse` for example) and map them to desired one (`PersonHolder` for example) and then work with that type (serialize, manipulate, etc).

If for some reason you don't want to do that you can look into the [`JsonNode` APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/use-dom#use-jsonnode) to dynamically manipulate JSON. For example handling can look something like the following (possibly should be split into 2 branches):

Data:

```cs
var json = """
        {
         "Employee": [
           {
             "FName":"Abc",
             "LName":"pqr"
           },
           {
             "FName":"pqr",
             "LName":"pqccr"
           }
        ]
        }
        """;
```

```cs
var studentsRoot = JsonNode.Parse(json).AsObject();
if (studentsRoot.Remove("Students", out var person) 
    || studentsRoot.Remove("Employee", out person))
{
    var replacements = new[]
    {
        ("FirstName", "First_Name"),
        ("LastName", "Last_Name"),        
        ("FName", "First_Name"),
        ("LName", "Last_Name"),
    };
    foreach (var jsonNode in person.AsArray())
    {
        var obj = jsonNode.AsObject();
        foreach (var replacement in replacements)
        {
            if (obj.Remove(replacement.Item1, out var val))
            {
                obj.Add(replacement.Item2, val);
            }
        }
    }

    studentsRoot.Add("Person", person);
}

var jsonString = studentsRoot.ToJsonString();
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple approaches to solve this task. The best option depends on the context:

- Are you doing just on-the-fly JSON transformation? Or maybe you need to read different sources and deserialize them into objects to work with them in your application?
- How many different data sources you have?
- What is the probability of changes to the format you receive data in?

In the generic case, I would define some interface like:

```cs
interface IPeopleReader
{
    IEnumerable<Person> Read(string json);
}
```

And implement it for each of the data sources (e.g. `StudentReader` and `EmployeeReader`).

While you have the same structure with just different property names, you can have shared implementation like:

```cs
class PeopleReader : IPeopleReader
{
    private readonly string _collectionName;
    private readonly string _firstNameField;
    private readonly string _lastNameField;
 
    public PeopleReader(string collectionName, string firstNameField, string lastNameField)
    {
        _collectionName = collectionName;
        _firstNameField = firstNameField;
        _lastNameField = lastNameField;
    }
    
    public IEnumerable<Person> Read(string json)
    {
        var node = JsonNode.Parse(json);
        if (node?[_collectionName]?.AsArray() is { } array)
        {
            foreach (var item in array)
            {
                if (item?.AsObject() is { } obj)
                {
                    yield return new Person
                    {
                        FirstName = obj[_firstNameField]?.ToString(),
                        LastName = obj[_lastNameField]?.ToString()
                    };
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And just reuse it for your cases:

```
class StudentReader() : PeopleReader("Students", "FirstName", "LastName") { }

class EmployeeReader() : PeopleReader("Employee", "FName", "LName") { }
```

This way you can be flexible about implementations: you don't duplicate much code while the structure is the same and in case one of the sources will change its format, you can just update corresponding class to whatever code you want (e.g. define custom models within that class or do any other logic).